# Swift 3.0 source code build error

Tags: swift

These days I was trying to compile Swift 3.0 on macOS followed by the instruction which is on GitHub step by step, when I run `utils/build-script -x` shell, got a failue like this:

```
 ** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules /Users/knight/githubRepo/swift-source/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/Swift.build/Debug/add_custom_command_target-004471a8febeaad1237722247e0e4ace-Swift.o.build/Script-627C6DA99FFD4D7E8932585C.sh
(1 failure)
utils/build-script: fatal error: command terminated with a non-zero exit status 65, aborting
```

[command line result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVACO.jpg)

Does anybody met this problem before? Would you please show me your resolution?

Comment: did you add a build script command to your xcode project?

Comment: nope,  I installed the latest Xcode, but I didn't add any build script to my xcode project.  I cloned a piece of source code of 'swift' from https://github.com/apple/swift, the shell is provided by apple

Comment: Latest Xcode means Xcode 8 beta 6 right? And you switched the command line tools to that version? Either in Xcode preferences or in the terminal `sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/Xcode-beta6.app`

Comment: Yes,  I do switched the command line tools to the latest version,  it doesn't work either,  confused @ @